# Where can I find a book about the whole grammar?

Tags: discussion

Please, recommend me a book where I can find all(!) English grammar.(literally all grammar)

Comment: You can’t. It’s a pipe dream. For the best we have so far, try the *Cambridge Grammar of their English Language* (CGEL) by Huddleston and Pullum. Only 1,860 pages :) Note that this is intended to update and replace *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, because that one wasn’t comprehensive! And no such book will ever be. English is not dictated but discovered. No one writes the rules, they record the small subset we can figure out. And you will *not learn English* from reading a grammar; only practice will do that. Though the book will help you understand what’s going on better.

Comment: @Dan Bron Was 'Cambridge Grammar of their English Language' intentional?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I take credit for anything funny I say, intentional or not.

Comment: Others correctly say that you will not find a single work covering all of 'English grammar' – all the 'rules' and all the ways to explain why those are the right rules and exactly how they work. **There are more basic problems.** (1) Research (eg by Svartvik and Greenbaum) has shown that _even proficient linguists do not agree on whether certain sentences say are grammatical_. And (2) _There are different grammars_; not all analyses agree. So you'd need a Comprehensive book on English Grammars, even if everyone finally agreed on exactly which sentences were acceptable. Oh, and 'rules' change..

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you mean a _meta_-grammer? And don't forget a _meta-meta_-grammar?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I cannot guarantee that you will find a book that has everything there is to know about English grammar. You will have to learn by speaking and listening to native speakers as well as using grammar books to guide you. Also, English is ripe with exceptions to any rule you may learn, which you will have to master as you become more fluent and have more exposure to the language.

But for a start, try Jean Yates's *Master the Basics: English.* You can buy it here: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=jean+yates+master+the+basics&ref=nb_sb_noss

This book is for learners of English as a second language, and covers parts of speech, typical verb patterns in all tenses, verb tenses, rules for combining sentence elements, and rules for capitalization and punctuation.

Contained in the book are a pretest with answers, exercises with answers for every section, part of speech, and verb tense, as well as charts and examples to illustrate English language patterns.

You really do not need a book that is completely exhaustive, what you need is exposure to the language and it's rules and exceptions, and a good solid grammar book to guide you.

Comment: OP did rather specifically and emphatically ask for *literally all grammar*. See my [my comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532319/where-can-i-find-a-book-about-the-whole-grammar#comment1300362_532319) on that point. It’s nice to offer favorite learning material, but my sense is OP is trying to short circuit reading learning materials by “knowing the whole thing” (which is impossible of course, but answers should at least address that request by the OP).

Comment: Please read the guidelines at the Help Center. Requests for grammars, thesauri etc are off-topic on ELU and should not be 'answer'ed but migrated (if reasonable questions) to ELU.Meta. But you give a reasonable piece of advice (which should admittedly be a 'comment'). A comprehensive grammar? The Collins CoBuild monograph on articles has been mentioned on ELU – over 100 pages on using _a/an_ and _the_. And it's far from perfect, not covering the use of the indefinite article with non-count noun usages well, and not addressing at all Masters' work on the null (as opposed to the zero) article.

Answer (score 0):

No such book would ever be agreed upon in its entirety by everybody who speaks English—or even by a majority of people.

Unlike French, for instance, there is no universal authority on the rules of the language.

At best, you can find a handful of sources that detail many possible grammar rules. Some, even many, of those might be commonly agreed upon—but not always, and certainly not by everyone.

It also doesn't help that grammar can be localized. UK English can have different *specfic* rules (or conventions) of grammar from US English, for instance. And certain regions in various geographical locations, or certain people in various cultural groups, can have their own idiomatic conventions.